# Magento some Category view pages are not displaying Properly

Tags: magento-1.7

Please visit this link.

http://joinery.newtrendzonline.com/handles/led-lighting/led-flexible-ribbon.html

I added lot of products to this site. .

Now Category view pages started to display like in the above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checklist for whether items are in stock follows. Some will seem stupid until the first time you spend an hour trying to figure this problem out:

1. The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2. The products must be Enabled.
   3.Product must have a stock Quantity.
3. The product must be set to In Stock.
4. If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity     and be set to In Stock.
5. The product must be assigned to the target Category.
6. If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.

You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.